# mpi4py and ctypes - Python program with MPI exits whenever a single thread exits (through C++)

Tags: python, c++, ctypes, mpi4py

(The codes used here are similar to another question I posted today, but the two questions are different)

I am using a complex C++ code with a Python3 interface (using ctypes). For simplicity, I have copied a simple C++ code below to frame my question. The function exitOrNot() accepts an argument `index` and exits when the it equals 7.

**multi.cpp**

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib>

extern "C" int exitOrNot(int index) {
    int ret;
    if(index == 7) {
        std::cout << "EXITING... \n";
        std::exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else {
        sleep(1)
        ret = index;
    }
    return ret;
}
```

I create a shared library for the above program libmulti.so using the following command - `g++ -fPIC -shared -o libmulti.so multi.cpp`

In my Python module, I use mpi4py for parallel processing. In this simple example, I have two functions - ctypes_exitOrNot() to receive the C++ function from before, and multi() to iterate over many input arguments (in this example, 5*100=500 arguments).

**multi.py**

```
import numpy as np
from mpi4py import MPI
import ctypes

_multi = ctypes.CDLL('./libmulti.so')

def ctypes_exitOrNot(index):
    ret = _multi.exitOrNot(ctypes.c_int(index))
    return ret

def multi(N):
    comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
    rank = comm.Get_rank()
    N_threads = comm.Get_size()-1 # Thread 0 is used only for IO
    
    N_jobs = N
    N_jobs_per_thread = int(np.ceil( float(N_jobs)/float(N_threads) ))
        
    print("\nrank",rank,"N_threads",N_threads,"N_jobs_per_thread",N_jobs_per_thread,"\n")

    indices = range(rank-1,N_jobs,N_threads)
    
    if rank == 0: # IO thread             
        completed_ranks = []
        while True: # Wait to receive data until all threads are done
            status = MPI.Status()
            data = comm.recv(source=MPI.ANY_SOURCE,tag=MPI.ANY_TAG,status=status)
            received_rank = status.Get_source()
            
            if data == "done":
                completed_ranks.append(received_rank)
            else:               
                index_system = data["index_system"]    
                with open("completed.txt","a") as file_completed:
                    file_completed.write(str(index_system) + '\n')
                
            if len(completed_ranks)==N_threads:
                print("\nrank 0 -- all threads done; completed_ranks",completed_ranks,"\n")
                break

    else:
        for index_rank,index_job in enumerate(indices):
            index_system = index_job
            
            print("rank",rank,"index_system",index_system,"started")

            # EXITING CONDITION FROM EXTENAL C++
            ret = ctypes_exitOrNot(index_system)
            data = {"index_system":ret}

            print("rank",rank,"index_system",index_system,"ended")
            
            comm.send(data, dest=0, tag=index_system)
        
        # This thread is done
        data = "done"
        comm.send(data, dest=0, tag=index_system)
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    multi(5*100)
```

The important line of the above code is `ret = ctypes_exitOrNot(index_system)`. The integer argument passed to exitOrNot() is the index 0-499, and when these are separated into different threads, the thread with index 7 exits. For reference, my terminal command is - 'mpiexec -n 6 python3 multi.py'

I finally come to my question. When a thread exits through C++ (like in this case), the whole program exits i.e. all the other threads exit as well. However, when the same exit is done from within Python, the other threads continue running.

Is there any way for the other threads to continue running even when one of them exits through C++? (I cannot edit the actual C++ file itself)

Comment: `std::exit` terminates the entire process. It doesn't matter how it's called, it terminates the entire process. Perhaps the python environment uses separate processes and not execution threads.

Comment: Assuming "exit from Python" means `sys.exit()`, `sys.exit()` only exits the thread that called it and the Python process only terminates if all remaining threads are daemon threads.  Not the same as `std::exit()` in C++.

Comment: Is there a command to not exit the whole process through C++? Exiting only a single thread instead?